# Lighttpd rewrite - multiple variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I'm moving from Apache to Lighttpd and need to setup similar rewrite rules.

How would I go about having multiple folders creating  URL variables? This works well in Apache:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?x=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?x=$1&y=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 [L]
```

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
   "^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$" => "/index.php?x=$1",
   "^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$" => "/index.php?x=$1&y=$2",
   "^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$" => "/index.php?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3"
)
```